# How can i export iam configuration from one aws account and import to other aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-iam

I have a use case where i need all the aws iam groups and the policies attached to it. How can i export from one aws account and import to other.

I have used below command to get all the iam configuration.

`aws iam get-account-authorization-details`

How can i import the output of above command into other aws account to poppulate group and policies similar to the origin aws account.